# How to display selected values in multiple select dropdown in a Yii2 app?

Tags: php, arrays, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on Yii2. I am creating multiple select drop down using custom array like this.

In controller file:

```
$all_groups = Groups::find()->where(['=','group_created_by',$id])->orwhere(new Expression('FIND_IN_SET(:id_to_find, group_managers)'))->addParams([':id_to_find' => $id])->all(); // fetch all values

$selected_groups  = Groups::find()->where(['=','group_users',$updateId])->orwhere(new Expression('FIND_IN_SET(:id_to_find, group_users)'))->addParams([':id_to_find' => $updateId])->all(); // getting selected values

$all_groups_array = [];

 foreach ($all_groups as $group) {
     $all_groups_array[$group->id] = ucfirst($group->group_name);
 }
```

On render data on the view:

```
return $this->render('mngr_userupdate', [
                        'model' => $model,
                        'all_groups_array'=>$all_groups_array,
                        'case'=>$case,
                        'email_error' => 'false',
                        'applied_email' =>   '' ,
                      ]);
```

so it is creating array like this:

```
Array
(
    [11] => Mngr1 group
    [14] => Mngr 11 Group
)
```

In vies file:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'group_user[]')->dropDownList($all_groups_array,['multiple' => 'multiple']) ?>
```

It is working fine on create form for data insertion.  but how to create array using which I can display selected values on update form.

**Edit:**

I just found that if I use it like

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'group_user[]')->dropDownList($all_groups_array,['multiple' => 'multiple', 'options'=>['14'=>["Selected"=>true],'11' => ["Selected"=>true]]]); ?>
```

then it will start display values as selected. i.e. I have to create array like

```
[
'14'=>["Selected"=>true],
'11' => ["Selected"=>true]
]
```

For this I am using loop like as follows:

```
foreach ($selected_groups as $key => $value) {
           $sel_groups_array[$value] = '' // what should be there or else
          }
```

How can I create this array using loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created solution of my question, In case if anyone has the such kind of problem then he can use the loop like as follows:

```
foreach ($selected_groups as $group) {

  $sel_groups_array[$group->id] = array("selected"=>true);
}
```

and in the views file you can use the array for display selected multiple values as follows:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'group_user[]')->dropDownList($all_groups_array,['multiple' => 'multiple','options' => $sel_groups_array]); ?>
```

Because the structure to display multiple selected values on update form, it should be like as follows:

```
$form->field($model, 'group_user[]')->dropDownList($all_groups_array,['multiple' => 'multiple', 'options'=>['14'=>["Selected"=>true],'11' => ["Selected"=>true]]]); 
// here 14 and 11 I am using as example
```